# glm for groups with unequal variance: is there an R equivalent of this Stata code?

Tags: r, stata, glm

It is a well-known fact that when fitting regression models for groups, unequal variance between groups can cause trouble. Is there a way in R to account for this?

A solution for Stata was suggested in this presentation http://www.stata.com/meeting/fnasug08/gutierrez.pdf (Slides 9-17). The actual code, shown on Slide 14, is as follows:

```
# where I might normally specify 
. xtmixed . . . || id: boy ageXboy girl ageXgirl, nocons cov(un)
# instead I want
. xtmixed . . . || id: boy ageXboy, nocons cov(un) || id: girl ageXgirl, nocons cov(un)
```

Is there a similar solution in R?

Comment: Take a look at [nlme](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) and/or [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html).

Comment: Specifically, you will probably need to use the `pdBlocked` syntax in `lme`: you will probably need to see Pinheiro and Bates 2000 for reference.